# Passing params to php in android

Tags: php, android

I have a problem in passing my params to PHP in Android.

I have two activities. One read my database and fill the list with rows from the table in this data base. It works fine. Then when i click on the ListItem i send the id of specific item to another activity:

```
String identyfikator = ((TextView)
view.findViewById(R.id.identyfikator)).getText().toString();
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrzystanekKierunek.class);
in.putExtra(TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR, identyfikator);
startActivity(in);
```

In the 2nd activity i read sent id and here is my problem. I have checked if this works

```
Intent i = getIntent();        
identyfikator = i.getStringExtra(TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR);
```

and it works. I have updated editText with my identnyfikator and it shows me correct id. But when i'm trying send it to my PHP it returns blank activity. What is wrong with this code?
Here is the 2nd activity:

```
package com.example.mybusstop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class PrzystanekKierunek extends ListActivity {

    String identyfikator;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wyszukaniaList;

    private static String url_przystanek_kierunek = "http://10.0.2.2/mybusstop_php/przystanekkierunek.php";

    private static final String TAG_WYSZUKANIA = "wyszukania";
    private static final String TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR = "identyfikator";
    private static final String TAG_NAZWA = "nazwa";

    JSONArray wyszukania = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.przystanekkierunek);

        wyszukaniaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Intent i = getIntent();

        identyfikator = i.getStringExtra(TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR);

        new LoadKierunek().execute();

       /* ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String identyfikator = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.identyfikator)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrzystanekKierunek.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR, identyfikator);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
        */
    }

    class LoadKierunek extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PrzystanekKierunek.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Wyszukiwanie...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {           
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identyfikator", identyfikator));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_przystanek_kierunek, "GET", params);

            try {
                    wyszukania = json.getJSONArray(TAG_WYSZUKANIA);
                    for (int i = 0; i < wyszukania.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = wyszukania.getJSONObject(i);

                        String identyfikator = c.getString(TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR);
                        String nazwa = c.getString(TAG_NAZWA);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR, identyfikator);
                        map.put(TAG_NAZWA, nazwa);

                        wyszukaniaList.add(map);
                    }
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            PrzystanekKierunek.this, wyszukaniaList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] {TAG_NAZWA, TAG_IDENTYFIKATOR},
                            new int[] {R.id.nazwaItem, R.id.identyfikator});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and the PHP script:

```
<?php
$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db.connecting.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

//if (isset($_GET["identyfikator"])) {
    $ide = $_GET['identyfikator'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM przystanek WHERE identyfikator=$ide") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $response["wyszukania"] = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $kierunek = array();
            $kierunek["id"] = $row["Identyfikator"];
            $kierunek["nazwa"] = $row["Nazwa_przystanek"];
            $kierunek["gps_x"] = $row["Lokalizacja_gps_x"];
            $kierunek["gps_y"] = $row["Lokalizacja_gps_y"];
            array_push($response["wyszukania"], $kierunek);
        }
        $response["success"] = 1;

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Błąd wyszukania!";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
//}
?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that JSONParser is a utility you've created? (JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(url_przystanek_kierunek, "GET", params);)
Can you post that code?

Comment: Yes this is other class which is responsible for connecting my android with php/mysql. But i have solved my problem. The problem was in names of my variables.
i have changed $kierunek["id"] = $row["Identyfikator"];
to $kierunek["identyfikator"] = $row["Identyfikator"]; and it's all good now. Thanks Guys. I can't replay for my own post before 8h, so i have to just comment someone's post.

Answer (score 0):

what is the output, if you replace your php code with :

```
<?php
$res = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['identyfikator']),true);
echo $res
?>
```